# Why is Google Protobuf executed with my cpp app on mac

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, protocol-buffers, clang++

I recently started C++11 development on mac with clang and XCode 12 and I'd really like to understand this platform better.

I was testing overloading the global `new` and `delete` operators in an "empty" C++ program, but I noticed that 89 allocations made with the global replacement of `new` operator weren't deallocated with the global replacement of `delete` operator, which looks like a memory leak. (Maybe it's not, but why?)

When debugging the program, I found out that these allocations all came from wireless_diagnostics::google::protobuf.

So my questions are :

- What is Google protobuf and why does it appear in my program ?
- Why does it leaves these memory leaks (Or what appears to be memory leaks) ?
- Is there something to do about it ?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

size_t allocations = 0;

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
   void* ptr = malloc(size);
   if (!ptr) throw std::bad_alloc{};
   allocations++;
   return ptr;
}

void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
{
   free(ptr);
   allocations--;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   std::cout << allocations << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

(Can't comment so posting as answer)

**What is Google protobuf and why does it appear in my program**

I have used google protobuf for serialisation purposes.
It is like compressing data (structured) so that we don't have to send a lot of data over wire.

I couldn't understand why it would appear in your program though.
By a long shot, it might be related to your debugger?
It seems that wireless diagnostic is being done, so I can only think that debugger is doing that

Can you share some screenshot of output from debugger or anything? That might shed more light to it.